# iPhone: Cannot access NSManagedObjectContext using appDelegate

Tags: iphone, core-data, exc-bad-access, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have started with iPhone development sometime back and I am trying to implement core data in my application.

In the process of executing FetchRequest I am stuck at following code...

```
MYAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

While debugging the following error is displayed...

```
Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
```

When I run the app, it just crashes.

This error appears again and again when I press 'continue' button in debug mode.

I tried changing my code, to this.....

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication\ delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

This lets the app run but when I press the Simulator home button, the same error is displayed in console.

What could be going wrong over here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have a public accessor method for your application delegate. I would implement it like so, at the top of your AppDelegate.m

```
+ (MYAppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (MYAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

You may then access it using:

```
[[MYAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectContext]
```

Comment: This gives me a warning like `'MyAppDelegate' may not respond to '+sharedAppDelegate'` - `(Messages without a matching method signature will be assumed to return 'id' and accept '...' as arguments.)`

Comment: Did you `#import "MyAppDelegate.h"` in the file you attempt calling it from?

Comment: @m5h - Yes I did. `NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[MyAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectContext];` would give an error otherwise.

Comment: ShiVik, you need to add + (MYAppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate; to your .h file. It's a warning, but because the method exists it still finds it.

Comment: How is the code in this answer any different than the original post?  The pointer should be the same.